# Writing Conditional Statements in QGIS raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, con

What is the equivalent statement of the following expression in the QGIS raster calculator?

```
    Con(((Abs("DEM" - "FSMin") > 120) | (Abs("DEM" - "FSMax") > 120)), 1, 0)
```

I have no problem running this command in ArcMap but as soon as I paste it in QGIS the raster calculator there rejects it.

Answer (score 35):

You can create a condition by using a little 'trick':

Suppose you have a raster file (layer1) with values below 0 but you want only positive values.

```
("layer1@1" > 0 )
```

Is resulting in 1 when it is above 0 and is resulting in 0 when it is below 0.

```
("layer1@1" > 0 ) * "layer1@1"
```

When you multiply this with the raster value it will either be 0 or it will be 1 multiplied with the raster value.

Answer (score 15):

As of QGIS 3.22, the raster calculator supports [if statements](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#feature-add-if-function-to-raster-calculator). Depending on the naming of the layers and raster band numbering, it would be something like

```
if((abs("DEM@1" - "FSMin@1") > 120) or (abs("DEM@1" - "FSMax@1") > 120), 1, 0)
```