# Combining several mask rasters to obtain one single mask with binary values

Tags: qgis, raster, masking

I have a series of separate rasters which represent the cloud cover over the same area but in different months. Each raster has 2 values: nan for "no cloud" and 255 for "cloud". What i want to do is to create a single mask, where each pixel has a value of nan if ALL the separate rasters have nan as a value for that pixel, and a value of 255 if ANY raster (even only one is enough) has a value of 255 for that pixel. 
I'm using QGIS and I guess the raster calculator should be used for this, but I have no clue about how to do it and I've had no luck searching for solutions so far because I don't know how to even *call* the operation I'm trying to do. I tried to add the rasters but I got a weird result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you could do that without conditionals, and [Conditional Statements in QGIS raster calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110121/conditional-statements-in-qgis-raster-calculator) suggests (and I think too) that the default QGIS raster calculator doesn't support conditionals.

But that link provides a link to [RaserCalc](http://gis-lab.info/qa/rastercalc-eng.html), which is another calculator plugin that does support conditionals.

Alternatively, if you're ok with using the GRASS plugin, you could do this with `r.series input=your_map1,your_map2,... output=your_output method=average`. You could also use the GRASS raster calculator `r.mapcalc`, but `r.series` (I think) is or was really just a convenient raster calculator wrapper.

Comment: In the end, I solved the problem by using r.series through Qgis' Processing toolbox, it was the simplest solution but very effective.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is to set a '1' for 'no cloud' and '0' or 'nan' for cloud. Then you can just multiply them together and all the 1's make 1 and a single 0 sets it all to 0.

@user55937 has the solution, though I think it can do conditionals. Try something like:

```
not(("Raster1@1" = 255) OR ("Raster2@1" = 255))
```

which should return 1 if they are all not 255, and 0 if one is.