# Fill up space between different polygons within a given distance

Tags: qgis, fill

I used a water index (NDWI) to extract pixels from a raster, then turned it into a polygon layer. The goal is to create samples for image classification. Now, the resulting layer is kind of patchy, and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to fill up the space between those polygons that are within a certain distance (let's say 50 meters), and merge them. If that space could be filled, I guess it would be simple to merge, really. I'm using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: You could try buffer by 50m with dissolve then buffer by -50m to move the unaffected lines back to somewhere close to their original location.

Comment: You could play around with the raster to fill the gaps before you convert it to polygons. For example with [Raster Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110121/writing-conditional-statements-in-qgis-raster-calculator) to set the values above som threshold to 1 and the other values to 0. Adjust the threshold until the gaps are filled, then convert to polygons