# Use a conditional raster calculator formula with exponential from ArcGIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

I have following formula that works in ArcGIS within the `Raster calculator`:

```
Con (("%P%"-"%ETP%)<0, "%RUx%"*Exp (("%P%"-"%ETP%")/"%RUx"), Con (("%RUx%"+"%P%"-"%ETP%")<"%RUx%","%RUx%"+%P%"-"%ETP%","%RUx%"))
```

I want to use it in QGIS 3.16 or QGIS 3.4. I made some modifications to make it work in the `Raster calculator` of QGIS, but I still get an `Error parsing formula`:

```
if(("P@1" - "ETP@1" )< 0,"RUx@1" *(("P@1" - "ETP@1") / "RUx@1" )^2.71828, if (( "RUx@1"+"P@1"-"ETP@1") < "RUx@1" ,"RUx@1"+"P@1" - "ETP@1","RUx@1"))
```

Which modifications are needed to make it work?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110121/writing-conditional-statements-in-qgis-raster-calculator

Comment: @BERA Thank you. I already read this topic and tried to apply it to my case unsuccessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
(("P@1" - "ETP@1" < 0)*"RUx@1" *("P@1" - "ETP@1") / "RUx@1" ^2.71828)+( "RUx@1"+"P@1"-"ETP@1" < "RUx@1" *"RUx@1"+"P@1" - "ETP@1"*"RUx@1")+"RUx@1"
```

`*` symbol should be used instead of `,`

`+` symbol should be used between two conditions