# Change detection for raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster, land-cover, land-use, change-detection

I'm working with multiple raster layers representing LULC data, Corine maps, from various years. My goal is to identify the pixels that have undergone change and determine the specific transitions between classes (e.g., how many pixels shifted from class X to class Y). I am utilizing QGIS for this task. Could anyone recommend the appropriate tools or suggest an efficient workflow for this analysis? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110121/writing-conditional-statements-in-qgis-raster-calculator for a few pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (SCP)](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) to calculate the land cover change. It will give the change on the basis of each class. The layers need to be projected before going to the operation.

[image]

[Link to the workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XKgVwrztXY)